# Error in binding a UDP socket

Tags: sockets, udp, bind, ip-address

I have a program which goes this way.

```
{
              memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
               /* fill the hints struct */
                hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
                 hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
                //hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
                hints.ai_protocol = 0;
                //hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
                hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
                hints.ai_addr = NULL;
                hints.ai_next = NULL;


                if(iFamily == AF_INET)
                    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;


                else if(iFamily == AF_INET6)
                        hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;

         /* Code for getting gettaddressinfo */

                if(iFamily == AF_INET)
                {

                iRet = bind(SockIPC, res->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
                char sBuff[1024];
         sprintf(sBuff, "errno [%d] ", errno);
               fp=fopen("debug.log","a+");
               fprintf(fp,"IPv4 bind error\n ");
               fprintf(fp,"bind error = %s\n",sBuff);
               fclose(fp);
               fflush(stdout);
               }
}
```

In the above piece of code I am trying to bind a UDP socket created.

I am getting the following bind error

> bind error = 266

Which is address already in use.

Can anyone 
let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly. Also, you are printing `errno` without first checking that the `bind` call actually failed. Perhaps it actually succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

There's no evidence of a problem here. It's only valid to evaluate `errno` if the immediately prior system call has returned -1, and `perror("bind");` would have been a lot simpler:

```
if (bind(...) == -1)
{
    perror("bind");
}
else // continue with execution
```

However there almost certainly was an error, if not 266: `EADDRINUSE` is 98, not 266. `SOCK_STREAM` and `IPPROTO_UDP` don't go together. You need `SOCK_DGRAM` and `IPPROTO_UDP`.

Comment: Are error numbers actually standardised? Also, the code in the question doesn't set IPPROTO_UDP - that line is commented out.

Comment: They aren't 'standardized' but they are pretty standard. And if you haven't specified IP_PROTO_UDP you need to. I suggest you get rid of all the irrelevant commented-out code so we can see what you actually did. And the major point remains, that there is no evidence of an actual error here.

Comment: (previous comment deleted because I realised the OP specifically does say they want UDP). However it's worth noting that EADDRINUSE has different values between Linux and FreeBSD for example - I don't think the numbers are even "pretty" standard.